# Force return from function while debugging

Tags: matlab, debugging

I am debugging a program in MATLAB R2016a and would like to return from a sub-function without completing the function. For example, you can write in code:

```
if(conditionMet)
  return;
end
```

If the condition is met, it will force the function to end early and continue in the caller code. While I am debugging, I would like to force the function to end early as if I had encountered a `return` command. When I simply type `return` while in debug mode, nothing appears to happens. Is there a way to force a function to end early and continue running?

Comment: I think you want to write command 'return' in command window to leave the method in middle of execution and do not think it is possible. I think solution provided by @m7913d is the only option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is not possible in general with the current release of Matlab.

If you know at beforehand at which place(s) you potentially want to return from your function while debugging, you can use the following trick.

```
function yourFunction ()
    breakDebug = false;
    ...
    if breakDebug
        return; % location at which you may break your function during debugging
    end
    ...
    return;
end
```

By setting `breakDebug` while debugging, the program will break at your next potentially break location.

Answer (score 4):

According to [MATLAB Central](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/11530-detect-debug-mode) and [Undocumented Matlab](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/undocumented-feature-function), there is an undocumented function `feature()` that could be used in your case like this:

```
if feature('IsDebugMode')
   return;
end
```